# System.Windows.Input.Key: square brackets in xaml?

Tags: wpf, xaml, key-bindings

Using XAML, I want to declare a KeyBinding with Modifiers="Control" and Key="[". The '[' character is not part of the System.Windows.Input.Key enum. How can I declare this KeyBinding in XAML?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Key.OemOpenBrackets` & `Key.OemCloseBrackets`

Just tested it with this:

```
<Window.CommandBindings>
    <CommandBinding Command="Help" Executed="Help_Executed" CanExecute="Help_CanExecute"/>
</Window.CommandBindings>
<Window.InputBindings>
    <KeyBinding Key="OemOpenBrackets" Command="Help" Modifiers="Control"/>
</Window.InputBindings>
```

```
private void Help_Executed(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("!");
}

private void Help_CanExecute(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    e.CanExecute = true;
}
```

Works for me with or without modifier, possibly the control you declared the binding on is out of focus. Another cause might be the keyboard layout, but i am not sure how the keys are resolved.